# Cannot load dll assembly in windows 10 (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)

Tags: powershell, dll, scripting

I was trying to load the compiled dll assembly of  [JSON.NET](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases). However I get the following error message:

```
PS C:\Users\tamas\Desktop\garbage> Add-Type -path .\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Add-Type : Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\tamas\Desktop\garbage\Newtonsoft.Json.dll' or one of its d
ependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Type -path .\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], FileLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

On a different computer, under windows 7 I was able to do the same thing without any problem. 
What could be the cause and the solution?

My .NET version:

```
PS C:\Users\tamas\Desktop\garbage> [System.Environment]::Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      30319  42000
```

PowerShell version:

```
PS C:\Users\tamas\Desktop\garbage> $Host.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14393  206
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @martin-brandl 's suggeston I was able to figure out the problem (I actually had to modify his code, becuase it did not output anything (`$global:error[0].Exception` has no *LoaderExceptions* field.))

```
PS C:\Users\tamas\Desktop\garbage>
>> try
>> {
>>     Add-Type -Path .\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>> }
>> catch
>> {
>>         write-host $global:error[0].Exception.InnerException
>> }
System.NotSupportedException: An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which would have caused th
e assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not enabl
e CAS policy by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox the assembly, please ena
ble the loadFromRemoteSources switch. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information.
```

It turned out that since the dll file was from an external source, for safety reasons powershell threw an exception. Using th `UnsafeLoadFrom(...)` method I was able to load the dll assembly:

```
PS C:\Users\tamas\Desktop\garbage> [System.Reflection.Assembly]::UnsafeLoadFrom("c:\users\tamas\Desktop\garbage\Newtonso
ft.Json.dll") # absolute path required here!!

GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
False  v4.0.30319     C:\Users\tamas\Desktop\garbage\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
```

More info on this issue can be found on the msdn site [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409252(VS.100).aspx) .

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you which of the dependencies you are missing but I can tell you how to find it out. Just surround your `Add-Type` within a `try-catch` cand retrieve the `LoaderException`:

```
try
{
    Add-Type -Path .\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
}
catch
{
        $global:error[0].Exception.LoaderExceptions | % { Write-Host $_ }
}
```

Comment: thanks! your answer helped to get me to the solution. See my answer to the question.